# Can't access database from Celery - OperationalError('no such table: products_product')

Tags: python, django, docker, celery

I have Django project and I can't access/query PostgreSQL from Celery. It affects any table even if it exists. Queries work well outside Celery, so I've done probably something wrong in Celery configuration. Celery tasks which not touch database works well.

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/app/accounts/tests.py", line 28, in test_access_to_database
    result_output = task.get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 217, in get
    self.maybe_throw(callback=callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 333, in maybe_throw
    self.throw(value, self._to_remote_traceback(tb))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 326, in throw
    self.on_ready.throw(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vine/promises.py", line 244, in throw
    reraise(type(exc), exc, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vine/five.py", line 195, in reraise
    raise value
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: products_product
```

Everything is based on docker's containers:

```
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Warsaw
  db:
    container_name: gallop_db
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file: ./env/dev/.envdb
  worker1:
    build: ./app
    command: celery -A gallop worker -l debug --pidfile=
    links:
      - redis
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/usr/src/app/
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - rabbitmq
  celery-beat:
    build: ./app
    command: celery -A gallop beat -l debug --pidfile=
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/usr/src/app/
    links:
      - redis
    environment:
      - TZ="Europe/Warsaw"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - rabbitmq
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:latest
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Warsaw
  volumes:
    postgres_data:
```

My environment:

```
celery                       4.4.5
Python                       3.8 (I checked also on 3.7)
Docker                       3.3
Django                       2.2.10
django-celery-beat           2.0.0
django-celery-results        1.2.1
```

Registered apps:

```
DJANGO_APPS = (
#...
    'celery',
    'django_celery_results',
    'django_celery_beat',
)
```

Celery in Django settings:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://rabbitmq' 
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://redis'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = False
CELERYD_TASK_SOFT_TIME_LIMIT = 60
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/Warsaw'
```

Celery task:

```
@app.task(bind=True, ignore_result=False)
def get_first_product(self):
    p = Product.objects.first()
    return p
```

Celery configuration (celery.py in project dir):

```
import os
from celery import Celery


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'gallop.settings')


app = Celery('gallop', )

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

Calling Celery task:

```
get_first_product.delay()
```

Comment: How does your celery tasks connect to postgres? I mean where is the configuration?

Comment: I've just added configuration to main post.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I added environment variables file to the worker and beat containers in my docker compose file:

```
env_file: ./env/dev/.env
```

By the way it's solved also my second error:

```
SMTPServerDisconnected('please run connect() first')
```

I couldn't send an e-mail from Celery, and again, outside Celery I haven't any problem. In that file I have an e-mail and a database configuration:

```
SQL_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql
SQL_DATABASE=your_database
SQL_USER=username
SQL_PASSWORD=your_password
SQL_HOST=db
SQL_PORT=5432
EMAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
EMAIL_HOST_USER=your_email
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=your_password
EMAIL_PORT=587
```